# Dúvidas de como identificar um objeto da coleção

Tags: c#, linq

Estou estudando C# e estou com algumas dúvidas.. O projeto que estou fazendo é um sistema de uma galeria fictícia que registra os Artistas, Curadores e peças de artes.

Eu criei a classe abstrata "Persons" que contém o primeiro e íltimo nome da pessoa, e duas classes (Artist e Curator) que herdam de "Persons" e que possuem as variáveis artistID e curatorID respectivamente e os devidos construtores.

Criei a classe ArtPiece, que guarda todas as informacoes da peca de arte e depois disso, criei tres classes/colecoes (Artists, Curators e Pieces) herdando de IEnumerable e implementando dois metodos.

Classe/Colecao Artists:

```
List<Artist> artists = new List<Artist>();
public void Add(Artist artist) {artists.Add(artist);}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {return artists.GetEnumerator();}
```

Classe/Coleção Curators:

```
List<Curator> curators = new List<Curator>();
public void Add(Curator curator) {curators.Add(curator);}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {return curators.GetEnumerator();}
```

Classe/Coleção Pieces:

```
List<ArtPiece> pieces = new List<ArtPiece>();
public void Add(ArtPiece piece) {pieces.Add(piece);}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {return pieces.GetEnumerator();}
```

Na classe Gallery (a principal), instanciei as coleções da seguinte forma:

```
Artists artist = new Artists();
Curators curators = new Curators();
Pieces artPieces = new Pieces();
```

E agora, ainda na Classe Gallery, preciso fazer o método para venda de uma peça de arte, onde vai ser atualizado o status da peça e adicionado comissão para o Curador que esta associado a mesma pelo curatorID. os únicos dois parâmetros que este método recebe é o preço pela qual a peça foi vendida e o ID da mesma e retornando true caso venda com sucesso, ou false caso a operação não seja realizada, ficando assim:

```
public bool SellPiece(string pieceID, double price) {}
```

Como consigo, pelo ID da peca, mudar o status dela para vendido, pegar a informacao do ID do curador associado a ela e, pelo ID do curador, adicionar a devida comissao a ele?

Tentei usar

```
var piece = artPieces.Where
```

Pra pegar o objeto ArtPiece que tem o ID passado como parâmetro, mas nem me aparece a opcao *.Where* pra usar..

Tentei deixar o menos "enrolado" possível essa pergunta..

Comment: Decidi usar Gets e Sets para percorrer nos objetos ate encontrar os necessarios e fazer as devidas alteracoes!

Comment: Usa expressão Lambda

Answer (score 0):

O `.Where()` não funciona no `artPieces` porque ele não é um `IEnumerable`, ele é um objeto que contem uma lista. A melhor forma de pegar o objeto pelo id seria:

```
var artPiece = artPieces.pieces.Single(piece => piece.Id == pieceID);
```

O single garante que só trará um objeto. Caso retorne mais, ou menos, dará excessão.

Lembrando que para fazer isso, o atributo `Id` deve ser publico.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!